# How to list TODO: in Ant build output

Tags: java, ant, build, tags

> Related: [How to use ant to check for tags (TODO: etc) in java source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636520/how-to-use-ant-to-check-for-tags-todo-etc-in-java-source)

---

How can I get ant to list `TODO:` tags found in my code in the build output when I run it.  I would like build failure to be *optional* (ie: a setting) if they are found.

---

I've tried [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/index.html) as suggested in the related post, but it doesn't display the text of the `TODO:`.

IE:

```
[checkstyle] .../src/Game.java:36: warning: Comment matches to-do format 'TODO:'.
[checkstyle] .../src/Game.java:41: warning: Comment matches to-do format 'TODO:'.
[checkstyle] .../src/GameThread.java:25: warning: Comment matches to-do format 'TODO:'.
[checkstyle] .../src/GameThread.java:30: warning: Comment matches to-do format 'TODO:'.
[checkstyle] .../src/GameThread.java:44: warning: Comment matches to-do format 'TODO:'.
```

Comment: which of those solutions did you try?  And which didn't work?

Comment: @Woot4Moo I'm try to use checkstyle, and I got it to list TODO: but it doesn't list the text of the TODOs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this provides the ability to fail a build if a todo is found but it may be usefull http://code.google.com/p/ant-todo/

Comment: Does this task have its equally evil twin `<fixme>`? :)

Comment: This task finds FIXMEs too :)